# Can anyone help me identify this transformer?

Tags: transformer, amperage

[image: Transformer photo 1]
[image: Transformer photo 2]

I'm trying to make a project using used part from a radio with my basic electronics knowledge.

I want to convert this AC 9.7V to a steady DC 3V using a diode bridge so I need to know what I'm working with (Amp wise) to define the diodes & capacitor I need to use.

I did'nt find anything on the net using the codes written on the transformer; all I know is that input supports 120V @ 60hz and it seems to output 9.7V.

The radio where I took the transformer from also has a backup 9V connector so could I assume that the amps is about the same as a 9V battery outputs (~450mah)?

Comment: Most transformers are custom with no datasheet available. You manage to determine 9.7 V AC output? If you measure the cross section area on the secondary side wire, you can guesstimate the current rating. Please note that mAh is a (battery) current capacity, not a current. You are after the output current rating. A step down from 9.7 V AC to 3 V DC cries for a switch mode converter unless you are planning for a huge heatsink and waste a majority of the power available.

Comment: Please explain how would the transformer "amperage" have anything to do with what kind of diode bridge or smoothing capacitor you need? Those are defined by your load. What are you powering, how much current at 3V it needs?

Comment: A transformer that size has about 3..6 VA. So if the output is 9V, it can supply about 500mA. Which is the ballpark figure for a radio clock.

Comment: Specifically, what is the part number and maker of the radio?

Comment: "mAh" (milli-amp-hours) is a bettery *capacity* rating. It tells you little to nothing about the instantaneous current output of the battery in **mA** (milli-amps) (no 'h' for hours on the end).

Comment: @winny Oh, Thanx for the info :-) a huge heatsink would be required to drop only 6V !? How would I go implementing a "switch mode converter" with the parts I have?

Comment: @Justme I'm trying to extract the "time wall projector" portion of the radio to make the device more portable. So the load(s) is/are a timing circuit (to keep the time) and a led that projects the time on the wall... I don't know how much current is needed; that's what I'm trying to figure out... I Get how the bridge concept works but I miss some knowledge about the current and how to step down the voltage properly...

Comment: @brhans Thanx, That makes sense... It's the first time I build a circuit with many components, I lack a little knowledge about concrete handling of the current lol

Comment: You are welcome! If I where you I would buy a ready made switch mode buck converter which can accept 12+ V input, set the output to 3 V and you are done.

Comment: @winny I'm trying to find existing components a purpose instead of just throwing them away... I like a challenge lol And I've always wanted to expand my knowledge of electronics! I managed to lower the voltage to ~1.5v using a single resistor (no bridge yet) and neither the resistor or the connected led seems to emit any heat after 30sec... Is'nt that a good solution to step down the power?

Comment: No, certainly not a good idea. You need either a linear regulator or preferably a switch mode one.